# Circular Redirect Path: Facebook + One Paged theme

Tags: wordpress, facebook, redirect

Using a theme that calls in other pages and posts so that they all appear on one 'page' I wonder if this is why I get redirect errors from Facebook / Open Graph Data.

Facebook says:

> Could not follow redirect path...these are the redirects we had to follow:

1. original - http://sethums.com/the-book
2. 301 - http://sethums.com/the-book
3. og:url - same thing

Why if the urls are identical is there a redirect? And what can be done to make the correct data appear? I'm using Yoast's SEO for Wordpress plugin. And filled in the social data.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: `http://sethums.com/the-book` redirects to `http://sethums.com/the-book/` – and the latter says its `og:url` was `http://sethums.com/the-book`, so Facebook would request that again … and then that would redirect, again …

Comment: Not sure I understand WHY there needs to be a redirect. We want facebook sharing to go to sethums the book page only. What am I not understanding?

Comment: It is _your site_ that is issuing the redirect from the version without a trailing slash to the one with one (standard WP behavior, I think) – but then your `og:url` tag value says, “hey, wait, this isn’t the actual URL of this item – then one _without_ the slash is!” You just need to make those two “directives”, instead of contradicting each other.

Comment: I went through the site again looking for instances of using the ' / ' at the end of the url and found nothing obvious. But then saw in Yoast documentation that his plugin automatically creates a canonical link, so I am guessing that's where the / came from.  I changed the WordPress url and the Site address in the General settings (both urls now have a / at the end). Do you think this will do it?  Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Your page still redirects to the URL with the trailing slash when the one without it is requested, and your `og:url` still says `http://sethums.com/the-book` – so no, nothing is fixed.

Comment: The sharing now shows up correctly even though I still get the same redirect errors.  I don't know where else to look - I did a find/search through the whole theme and no mention of canonical. Only the Yoast plugin. Where does one put the og:url?